# Scan a directory for new files and copy the file to new location and delete source file

Tags: java

Hey guys I want to create a Java program that monitors a directory for a new file (zip file), for a specific time period (2 minutes). To make sure there are no further changes before copying the file to the destination folder. Once the file is copied to the destination directory, compare the sizes of the source file and the destination file, if they are same delete said file from the source folder; once the file has deleted unzip the zip file .

```
Sourcefolder/File1.zip
Destinationfolder/file1.zip
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: Serious question: why? There are so many tools that can already do this, why not just use one of those instead? Especially the kind that you can chain, where the watcher just triggers "anything", and you call a different thing to run your actual task.

Answer (score 2):

Look into Java's [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) API to monitor a directory for changes. The rest should be basic file IO after that.

Example for watching directories:

```
public class DirectoryWatcherExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WatchService watchService
          = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

        Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"));

        path.register(
          watchService, 
            StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, 
              StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, 
                StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

        WatchKey key;
        while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                System.out.println(
                  "Event kind:" + event.kind() 
                    + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ".");
            }
            key.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio2-watchservice